# How can I merge every 2 arrays into 1 and append to new array (outside of loop) in foreach loop?

Tags: php

I have a result from an sql query:

```
 array(4) {
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["question_category"]=>
    string(11) "Engagement"
    [0]=>
    string(11) "Engagement"
    ["result"]=>
    string(6) "6.6667"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "6.6667"
    ["employee_first_name"]=>
    string(5) "Person A"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "Person A"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["question_category"]=>
    string(9) "Tenure"
    [0]=>
    string(9) "Tenure"
    ["result"]=>
    string(6) "7.6667"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "7.6667"
    ["employee_first_name"]=>
    string(5) "Person A"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "Person A"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["question_category"]=>
    string(11) "Engagement"
    [0]=>
    string(11) "Engagement"
    ["result"]=>
    string(6) "7.6667"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "7.6667"
    ["employee_first_name"]=>
    string(6) "Person B"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Person B"
  }
  [3]=>
  array(8) {
    ["question_category"]=>
    string(9) "Tenure"
    [0]=>
    string(9) "Tenure"
    ["result"]=>
    string(6) "8.3333"
    [1]=>
    string(6) "8.3333"
    ["employee_first_name"]=>
    string(6) "Person B"
    [3]=>
    string(6) "Person B"
  }
}
```

And I want to end up with a results array:

```
$results = array(['x' => 6.6667, 'y' => 7.6667],['x' => 7.6667, 'y' => 8.3333]);
```

With 'x' being this 'result':

string(11) "Engagement"
["result"]=>
string(6) "6.6667"

and 'y' being this 'result':

string(9) "Tenure"
["result"]=>
string(6) "7.6667"

fyi... "result" is AVG('result') from DB GROUP BY question_category,...

I've been stuck on this for a while now, so I'd really appreciate some input!

Comment: [`array_chunk()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk) and a loop.

Comment: Though now that I think about it you could probably rearrange the query to do all of this for you in a way that doesn't rely on the rows being in a certain order.

Comment: Your question is so convoluted that I read over 15x and still don't understand if you want an array with key 'x' with value '6.6667' or with value "string(11) \"Engagement\" [\"result\ "]=> string(6) \"6.6667\" "

Comment: I agree, solve this at the database level. You've got a GROUP BY, and it sounds like you just need to further arrange/group by employee somehow

Comment: Thanks @Sammitch for the input, agreed - the most efficient way would be to somehow write a better SQL query, I'm just finding it difficult getting to grips with the logic and translating it to SQL!

Comment: Hint: You can join a table to itself, and have more than one condition in the JOIN statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in the comments, I'd recommend solving this in SQL. But if for whatever reason you can't, just group by employee name, and map the question category to x or y as needed.

```php
$data = [
    [
        'question_category' => 'Engagement',
        'result' => '6.6667',
        'employee_first_name' => 'Person A',
    ],
    [
        'question_category' => 'Tenure',
        'result' => '7.6667',
        'employee_first_name' => 'Person A',
    ],
    [
        'question_category' => 'Engagement',
        'result' => '7.6667',
        'employee_first_name' => 'Person B',
    ],
    [
        'question_category' => 'Tenure',
        'result' => '8.3333',
        'employee_first_name' => 'Person B',
    ],
];

$grouped = [];
foreach($data as $row){
    // I think this is the mapping? If anything else exists,
    // this will throw
    $xOrY = match($row['question_category']){
        'Engagement' => 'x',
        'Tenure' => 'y',
    };
    
    // Group by name
    $grouped[$row['employee_first_name']][$xOrY] = $row['result'];
}

// Remove the names (optional)
$grouped = array_values($grouped);

var_dump($grouped);
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/PN1t4#v8.2.7

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look into this Chris, I appreciate it!